# What is the 'quiet' version of reciting?

Tags: word-request, verbs

I have often used the verb **"recite"** to mean `reading from the memory`. But just recently found that the accurate meaning is doing it aloud or in front of an audience:

Cambridge dictionary:

> to repeat aloud from memory.
>
> *She recited a poem in front of the class.*

Oxford Learner's:

> [transitive, intransitive] to say a poem, piece of literature, etc. that you have learned, especially to an audience.

**So is there another synonymous verb that means just saying/repeating a poem, not aloud and by oneself?**

For example:

I was ________ this poem while walking back home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Subvocalize" may be the proper terminology but it would not be my first choice. I don't have a single neat word for it; instead I would use "recite" and modify it to make it clear I wasn't actually speaking aloud:

> I was **reciting this poem in my head** while walking home.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ‘subvocalise’.

> Utter or form (words or sounds) with the lips silently or with barely audible sound, especially when talking to oneself, memorizing something, or reading.
>
> [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/subvocalize)]